# Thunderstorm reseting my micro-controller

Tags: power, reset, security

I think this is a follow up from my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539031/why-does-a-thunder-storm-trigger-my-house-alarm?noredirect=1#comment1396325_539031). If not then please ignore it.

I have created a very basic (crude) alarm system that uses a reed switch. Luckily there was a thunderstorm and some lighting to test out the system. Below is a schematic of the system.

The works as expected, when the magnet is moved away from the reed switch the alarm is activated and sounds the siren. The 12V input is supplied via a [Sherlo 3.2A Backup supply](https://www.sherlotronics.co.za/power-supply-12vdc-3-2a/). The buck converter is a DC-DC SWITCHMODE BUCK MODULE LM2596. The reed switch is attached to a wooden door and I checked the sensitivity of the reed switch. The magnet needs to be at least 2cm away from the reed switch, so there is a bit of play.

However what I noticed when the thunder came, was the micro-controller reset itself when the thunder started. I know it resets because at the beginning of the code the siren is activated for 3 seconds and then goes off until the reed switch is triggered. I am not sure why this happened.

What additional circuitry can I use to prevent the micro from reseting?

I will bridge the Vcc with the AVcc pin using a wire.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117707/discussion-on-question-by-joey-thunderstorm-reseting-my-micro-controller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH1bPs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If Relay switching current is 500mA max and contact R init. = MAX 200 mΩ  with 5V across Cap Imax= 25A neglecting wire resistance.

Then use Twisted pair throughout or STP wire.

Added R2 may be reduced to  10mA which is the typical Reed Relay longest MTBF rating (mechanical stress only)  Thus 5V/10mA= 470 Ohm to 1k (5mA)  . Although magnet operated glass gas-filled Reed Relays do not oxidize like non-gold contact air exposed switches which require 10% rated wetting current. Reeds ought to be good from 0 to 500mA unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Just to be sure can you indicate where the line going to the micro for the triggering will be?

Comment: Is there a need to put a TVS from Trig+ to the ground? And do you think these transients that are created in the cable during lighting responsible for the uC resetting itself?

Comment: "Resets" can occur from high dV/dt  E fields or high dI/dt H fields  on either ground shift + or Vin -ve and expect ringing, so this will dampen and attenuate the impulse in either case. If your cable is quite long you can be more aggressive with a 100Hz LPF

Comment: The cable is about 5 meters long, does this warrent a 100Hz LPF and how do I determine what LPF I need giving a lenght of cable. Can you also explain the "R2 limits Reed contact discahrge current arc."?

Comment: Sorry for bombarding you with questions. So this setup is for a sensor. Does a power supply cable also need this setup or will a decoupling capacitor on the PCB power input suffice?

Comment: YES, yes usually.  but even switching regulators can get an AC line disturbance and affect the DC output so it all depends on the levels of disturbance on the conducted AC line affect on 12VDC line if at all. Unregulated supplies with transformers usually attenuate input AC glitches to 0.1% on DC output

Comment: okay, so is it better to use a decoupling capacitor or an LPF?

Comment: R1 needs to be on the contact  side of R2 and lower value - 4K7 at a quick guess so that enough current flows to counteract other induced signals and to ensure enough ‘wetting’ current for the switch contacts.

Comment: Reeds are inert gas filled <?>  so no wetting current, only max switching current.  RC is the time constant for a LPF as per eqn. in fine print

Comment: I didn't pay attention to other issues like floating Reset inputs or Decoupling caps, so check for other issues

Comment: Aye re the wetting current. We are also assuming the switch actually a reed sw, but that is secondary to the issue. Nevertheless, you do want a few mA to flow. 1k would be a better choice.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I have made the final design and included what you said. Is this design now up to par?

Comment: @Joey In your updated circuit board layout, TRIG+ goes straight to the microcontroller. That's not what the above circuit diagram says. Seems there is still a mistake in there.

Comment: @Unimportant yes, silly error. Thanks for picking it up. I have updated the circuit and posted the new design above.

Comment: schematic is still bogie