# Is a ferrite sleeve better than a low-pass filter in order to protect a PCB from EMI caused by lightning

Tags: power, emi-filtering

**Follow up from previous [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539173/thunderstorm-reseting-my-micro-controller?noredirect=1#comment1397007_539173). This post is different because I am now focusing on the power cable and thus the power input of the PCB.**

[image]

This post is related to the EMI produced. I wrote a different post of the surge component [part](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539727/how-does-common-mode-voltage-surges-couple-in-wires)

I want to apply power to a PCB. The length of the power cable is around 12 meters. The power cable will be carrying 12V DC @ 2.2A. The power cable is running along a wall and it placed on the outside of the wall. It will be enclosed in a plastic conduit.

Sticking to the topic of lightning and EMI caused by it. From the previous post, I know when lightning strikes, the EMI created by it will cause some form of EMI in the power cable and thus the PCB. I therefore would like to know if applying a ferrite sleeve to the end of the power supply cable to supply the load (PCB) is better than designing a low-pass filter on the PCB board?

If the low-pass filter is better, what cut-off frequency should I aim for and how do I determine this cut-off (I know how to calculate the cut-off freq using R and C, I am asking what factors determine the cut-off frequency needed)?

*There is no direct earth connection to the PCB and the PCB is mounted in an IP55 plastic enclosure. The only power wires are the +12V and GND from the power supply. The only direct earthing is coming from the AC to DC 12V power supply. Where the plug is connected to mains via a three-pin plug (L, N, and E). The power supply is EMC tested. The surge is easy to prevent as I can install a surge protector plug on the side of the main. Is there no other way to prevent my circuit from these high-frequency EM that might couple into the power cable to the PCB, besides the decoupling capacitor (C1)?*

[image]

**Previous post PCB**

[image]

[image]

Comment: a ferrite bead basically *is* a low-pass filter.

Comment: @Hearth can you provide some advice on the last paragraph?

Comment: Consider using some surge arrestor component, such as a transil. But maybe more importantly, you should ask yourself what other cabling is going to enter/exit the box that you're building. The power supply input tends to be quite tolerant to abuse. To protect the circuitry of the box, you should limit the potentials at each signal port or terminal of the box to within some range around a Protective Earth potential, that you should have available near by... which raises a couple questions :-)

Comment: @frr "The power supply input tends to be quite tolerant to abuse." I am not concerned about the power supply input. I am concerned about the input to my PCB (i.e. not the 12V DC output power supply). "To protect the circuitry of the box, you should limit the potentials at each signal port or terminal of the box to within some range around a Protective Earth potential, that you should have available near by... which raises a couple of questions" can you provide more info on this pleaseeeeeee.... :)

Comment: given what you have told us it will be hard to be more specific.

Comment: I would say the ferrite bead or an on-board common-mode choke  in addition to an electrostatic shield in the enclosure connected to circuit ground will probably work well.

Comment: Also consider that if the final board is going to be switching some significant loads you probably want some bulk capacitance on the input to compensate for the rather long cable inductance and you might have to dampen the resulting LC.

Comment: @Unimportant I assume the bulk cap. will be C1 in the picture above? " you might have to dampen the resulting LC." can you provide more detail on this?

Comment: @Joey Easy to follow explanation here : https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J16/all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is a ferrite sleeve better than a low-pass filter in order to protect
> a PCB from EMI caused by lightning*

This question is a bit like asking whether you should use a fork or a whisk to beat the egg-white when making a soufflé. In other words, it totally misses the point.

A direct lightning strike will detonate your electronics no matter what you do so, what you should feasibly consider are, the effects of an **indirect lightning strike** because there is nothing you can do about a direct lightning strike.

**An indirect lightning strike** causes an earth potential bounce of several thousand volts. This means that electronics connected by a cable that are earthed at both ends might see a surge current of several thousand amps down the cable shield.

That is what you have to protect against and ferrites and filters won't help. You really have two choices: -

- Isolation techniques
- Surge protection devices

The devil is in the detail - without full knowledge of earths, cables and circuits, it's pointless trying to generalize any more. However, it's worth highlighting what a lightning surge profile looks like: -

[image]

Picture from [IEC 61000-4-5 standard overview](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00080038-iec-61000-4-5-standard-overview-stmicroelectronics.pdf) produced by ST.com.

And the thing to take away is the speed of the pulse; the fastest rise time is about 1.2 μs and so the dominant part of the spectrum is around 1 MHz. I mention this because a ferrite sleeve will be largely useless at this low speed.

---

Here's a diagram that should explain the surge problem you are facing: -

[image]

It's my interpretation of how [IEC 61000-4-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61000-4-5) performs earth bounce testing on equipment.

EMI is just air-bound interference. The surge (that you are trying to convince yourself is not to be considered in this question) is both damaging and highly interfering (much more so than an air-bound EM interference).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117786/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-is-a-ferrite-sleeve-better-than-a-low-pass-filt).