# How does common mode voltage surges couple in wires

Tags: power, surge-protection, common-mode, lightning

From doing some research and with the assistance of a user on this platform, I would like to know if my understanding of this concept is correct.

[image]

Please note this post is an add-on to this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539335/is-a-ferrite-sleeve-better-than-a-low-pass-filter-in-order-to-protect-a-pcb-from/539402#539402). A user decided to answer an unrelated issue in this post that was not needed. The previous post was related to the EMI issue and this post is related to the surge. The is basically a  [Lightning strikes, a natural phenomenon, are one of the key causes of EMI. Lightning surges are brief but powerful over-voltages and over-currents generally accompanied by EMI/RFI lasting up to a duration of a few hundred microseconds.](https://www.emisindia.com/lightning-surge-protection/) Hence the previous post was specifically to get rid of the EMI caused not the surge as in this post.

The power cable is a two-wire ripcord encased in a plastic conduit. The PCB box is also plastic. The sensor could any type of sensor.

I know that when indirect lightning strikes the earth's ground a few kilometers away, two types of surges are created. Namely differential and common-mode voltage surge. Now differential is measured between the two cables, where a common mode is measured between one of the cables and the earth's ground.

Common-mode voltage is a result of the parasitic capacitance that is formed between a power cable and the ground. This forms a capacitance because there exists potential in the earth's ground and the cable and the air in between the two is the dielectric. Hence a capacitance is formed. Now to get rid of the common mode surge you would apply a surge protector component like a TVS diode between the power cable or any other cable and the earth's ground as shown in the second picture. Were the picture shows it for one cable only. So in order to get rid a common-mode voltage surge, a surge protector needs to be incorporated into a PCB to connects the cable to earth's ground. Is this explanation correct or not?

[image]

[image]

Comment: *I know that when indirect lightning strikes a piece of electronic* - again, despite having been told to the contrary, you are still getting it wrong - indirect lightning does not strike at your electronics - it is indirect and causes ground or earth bounce or whatever term is the correct one.

Comment: I know where you are coming from but the EMI produced is "interference" and not damaging whereas the surge is much higher interference AND damaging. And, pretty much any solution that deals with the surge, deals with the EMI.

Comment: I was talking about the common-mode surge because it is the beast you need to fight. It can create a differential surge but the chief mechanism is common mode surge first then a capacitive imbalance to earth creating a differential (but significantly smaller) differential surge.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes  I have read that differential surges are easy to deal with when compared to common-mode surges. Firstly is there an animation that visually shows how these surges occur. It is sometimes very hard to understand these things and I have any equipment that enables to be replicate a safe experiment. Secondly I have read that applying a surge protector like a TVS diode from the input of the cables to earths ground will help with this massive surge. Is this true?

Comment: See the diagram addition to my answer in your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get rid of common-mode surges is with a common-mode filter/choke. For example both leads can be wrapped around a turoidal core so that the magnetic field produced by differential signals cancels out (they do not "see" the choke) and the common-mode signal adds together and it "sees" this inductance that is making it hard to pass through. Alternatively you could use a decoupling transformer at the end. A good example for you to check out are RJ45 Ethernet connectors because those are all about getting rid of common-mode noise. Btw. a surge protector is always a good idea so don't get rid of that.

Comment: I don't understand this because the common-mode surge is relative to the earth's ground. So how is all of that energy getting dissipated if the choke is not grounded to the earth's ground?

Comment: @Pangus so you telling me all I need to do is get a ferrite core and wrap the +12V and GND lines of the power around it or just put a common-mode choke in my PCB circuits the input terminals (+12V and GND). In way that the magnetic fields will add up for common mode signals? It is that easy?

Comment: @Pangus and these common-mode chokes are able to handle these large current and voltage impluse?

Comment: @Pangus and pgibbons I am not seeing a common-mode choke being used for surges. I so far have only seen them being used for common-mode noise suppression. Please provide more details on using common-mode choke for surges. If you cannot then please delete your answer because if you giving incorrect information this will be harmful, especially giving the voltages and currents these surges have. I am not talking about your common noise from data lines. Which is clearly stated in the flowchart.

Comment: Hi @Joey, The common-mode spike in the lightning is still relative to something else, in this case Earth/Ground. The voltage where the lighting strikes is immensely high, even though it is hitting ground at that point. The ground has resistance too, the current flowing from the lightning is causing a voltage gradient called step-voltage that diminishes the further you are away from the impact point. The copper wire has much less resistance and can carry a high common-mode voltage to another location, where relative to the earth/ground at the remote location it could be a very high voltage ...

Comment: ... with the common mode choke the energy is not really being dissipated but it is being blocked (actually reflected back). The reason is that during the spike, the voltage changes very fast, but if it has to go through an inductor, the inductor doesn't like fast changes, for the fast change (frequency) it represents a high resistance (impedance) and for the low frequency it represents a low impedance. At DC the inductor has just the resistance of the wire, which is very low. Since we're talking about a common-mode filter, any differential signals don't even "see" the inductor so those can ...

Comment: ... still use high-speed signals if "they want". As far as dimensioning the ferrite / the filter, I am not commenting on this. Whether the surge is low-voltage noise or from a lightning, the principal is the same but of course the dimensioning / rating has to be vastly different. For example the lightning wouldn't even notice the common-mode choke inside RJ45 plugs, it would just vaporize the whole thing into a little ball of plasma. Combining multiple filters (including your TVS diode) will be more effective. If you need to handle a direct lightning strike look up HAM-radio antenna arrestor.

Comment: indeed in principle a common-mode choke will work, but for application and the size of the common-mode choke I would need, will not work. I am not sure if it is in this post or the previous one, but what I will do and have seen is too use TVS diode for the +12V power line and for the GND (ground) line. Then ground these TVS diodes to the earth's ground via the mains grounding wire. Since the mains grounding is connected to the earth's ground via a long metal rod embedded into the ground.

Comment: the differential surge can be easily clamped using a surge protector at the input mains of the power supply as you suggested.